# TRAC invalid state, current state is no longer exist

Tags: trac

We have installed and configured TRAC, but facing below issue

Once tickets are assigned to developers, he cannot find them in validation; it shows an invalid state.

Regards,
Sam

Need Suggestion and Solution to fix the issue

Comment: You'll need to provide a more detailed report, including details such as the plugins and workflow (trac.ini) that you are using. Consider asking on the [Trac Users mailing list](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/MailingList).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.